# How I know User Account has been disable from AWS Backend

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have a user in AWS User Pools and I have disable this user from setting.So my question is how I get user account status from my App.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the listUsers api to get this user. In the response, value of Enables attribute would be false.

```
 var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion:'2016-04-18'}).
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers({

                                         "Filter": "username =\"<username>\"",                                             
                                        "UserPoolId": <PoolId>
                                    },function(err,resp){
                                        if(err){
                                            console.log(err);
                                        }else{
                                        console.log('user enabled = ', resp.Users[0].Enabled);
                                        console.log(resp);}})
```